# BrockAllen Identity Reboot - no longer functions on ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

Current project:

- ASP.NET 4.5.2
- MVC 5
- EF 6

So I have come across a bit of a wrinkle. I have been using the [BrockAllen Identity Reboot](https://brockallen.com/2014/02/11/introducing-identityreboot/) (BAER) to make my MVC 5 projects just that much more secure. Unfortunately, BAER appears to have stopped working. Even on a clean MVC 5 setup, with zero additional customization, adding all the required content paints the ITwoFactorCode in `IdentityModels.cs`:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser, ITwoFactorCode {
```

with:

```
'ApplicationUser' does not implement interface member 'ITwoFactorCode<string>.HashedTwoFactorAuthCode'
'ApplicationUser' does not implement interface member 'ITwoFactorCode<string>.DateTwoFactorAuthCodeIssued'
```

I have confirmed that this occurs on even a newly set up project with zero additional customizations. Apparently something has changed in DotNet in the last six months to render this NuGet package inoperative. I first ran into this issue when I tried to create a hybrid MVC/API project, but it affects pure MVC projects even as the first package added.

Suggestions? I have already tried to contact BrockAllen and <del>have come up with zero responses</del> finally managed to contact him via eMail. I have [opened an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/brockallen/BrockAllen.IdentityReboot/issues/14).

Comment: I know the project templates have changed (assuming you keep Visual Studio up to date). If you're not planning on using most of the OWIN template code, you might have better luck starting with an empty MVC project.

Comment: Unfortunately, I use Identity 2.0 rather extensively. It is a great help to have most everything scaffolded out on project creation.